# Find a square matrix with given properties about the dimension of the kernel of it's powers

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to provide an example of a $11 \times 11$ matrix with entries from a given field $k,$ such that $\dim \ker B = 4, \dim \ker B^2 = 7, \dim \ker B^3 = 9, \dim \ker B^4 = 11. $ I first set $B := C - \lambda I$ for some matrix $C$ of same dimension as $B.$ By noting $d_1 := \dim \ker B = 4, d_2 := \dim \ker B^2 - \dim \ker B = 3, d_3 := \dim \ker B^3 - \dim \ker B^2 = 2, d_4 : = \dim \ker B^4 - \dim \ker B^3 = 2,$ we can construct the Jordan normal matrix
$ A = S^{-1}CS $ with the typical shape containing one $4 \times 4,$ one $3 \times 3,$ and 2 $ 2\times 2$ Jordan boxes, whereby $S$ contains the generalized eigenvectors of $C.$ We have $C = SAS^{-1}$ and thus $B = SAS^{-1} - \lambda I.$ In order to provide such matrix $B$ I need to know $S.$ How can I go from here in finding $B$ ?

Comment: From what you say, it seems you just need to give an example of a matrix $B$ whose powers have the kernels of dimension $4,7,9,11$, so it seems that you can assume that $B$ is in Jordan normal form if you like.

Comment: $\lambda=0$ and the Jordan blocks are not what you wrote. There are $d_1$ blocks, among which $d_1-d_2$ of size $1,$ $d_2-d_3$ of size $2, $ $d_3-d_4$ of size $3$ and $d_4$ of size $4.$

Comment: @Anne Bauval. I still think my calculation about the structure of the Jordan normal form is correct. Assuming that you are right, how do you get the wanted $11\times 11$ matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessarily, $B=C$ and $\lambda=0$ for all the Jordan blocks (since $B^4=0$ and the only eigenvalue of a [nilpotent matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix) is $0$), and the blocks are not your "one $4 \times 4,$ one $3 \times 3,$ and 2 $ 2\times 2$ Jordan boxes", which would result in $\dim\ker B^2=8$ and
$\dim\ker B^3=10.$

Instead, among the $d_1=4$
blocks, there must be:

- $d_1−d_2=1$ block
  of size $1,$
- $d_2−d_3=1$ block
  of size $2,$
- $d_3−d_4=0$ block
  of size $3,$
  and
- $d_4=2$ blocks
  of size $4.$

This gives you the following $11\times11$ matrix:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}J_1(0)&0&0&0\\
0&J_2(0)&0&0\\0&0&J_4(0)&0\\
0&0&0&J_4(0)
\end{pmatrix},$$
for which you can visualize:
$$\begin{align}
\ker A&=\langle e_1,e_2,e_4,e_8\rangle, \\
\ker A^2&=\ker  A\oplus\langle e_3,e_5,e_9\rangle,\\
\ker A^3&=\ker A^2\oplus
\langle e_6,e_{10}\rangle,\\
\ker A^4&=\ker A^3\oplus
\langle e_7,e_{11}\rangle
\end{align}$$
where $(e_1,\dots,e_{11})$ is the canonical basis of $k^{11}.$

The matrices $B$ satisfying your four conditions on the dimensions of $\ker B^k$ are exactly the matrices having this $A$ as their Jordan normal form, i.e. the matrices similar to $A:$
$$B=SAS^{-1}$$
where $S$ is an arbitrary invertible $11\times11$ matrix.

Since you only want an example, take the simplest one, as first commented above by @krm2233: for $S=I_{11},$ $B=A.$

Comment: Many thanks. But I have learned that the Jordan normal form is built following the description at my posted question. One my draw a Young-tableau with columns being the $d_i$ values I showed above and the rows make up the sizes of the Jordan boxes. Then one can build the so called Krylov sequences to find the generalized eigenvectors. In fact, it turns out that with $\lambda = 0$ also my version of the Jordan normal form works. At least, $B^4 = 0.$ Can you comment on that, i.e. which is the correct Jordan form ? Also, by $e_i$ do you mean a canonical base vector ?

Comment: Given $B = SAS^{-1} - \lambda I, A$ the Jordan normal form w emay say we choose $\lambda = 0$ for simplification reasons. But what is the argument of claiming that $B = A$ will also be the Jordan normal form without knowing in advance $S$ ? Actually for getting $S$ one needs $C$ which we also do not know.

Comment: If you now understand, you can delete these 2 comments as well.

Answer (score 2):

For any matrix $B$, one has an increasing sequence of subspaces

$$0\subset \ker B \subset \ker B^2 \subset ... $$

With the dimensions of these given, we can choose a basis $e_1,...,e_{11}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\ker B&=\langle e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\rangle, \\
\ker B^2&=\langle e_1,e_2,...,e_6,e_7\rangle, \\
\ker B^3&=\langle e_1,...,e_9\rangle, \\
\ker B^4&=\langle e_1,...,e_{11}\rangle. 
\end{align*}
Then $Be_i=0$ for $i=1,2,3,4$, $Be_i\in \ker B=\langle e_1,...,e_4\rangle$ for $i=5,6,7$, $Be_i\in \ker B^2=\langle e_1,...,e_7\rangle$ for $i=8,9$ and $Be_i\in \ker B^3=\langle e_1,...,e_9\rangle$ for $i=10,11$. Note that $Be_i$ are the columns of $B$ in this basis, so the matrix looks like

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    0_{4\times 4} & * & * & * \\
    0_{3\times 4} & 0_{3\times 3} & * & * \\
    0_{2\times 4} & 0_{2\times 3} & 0_{2\times 2} & * \\
    0_{2\times 4} & 0_{2\times 3} & 0_{2\times 2} & 0_{2\times 2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This form ensures that $\ker B\supset \langle e_1,...,e_4\rangle$, $\ker B^2\supset \langle e_1,...,e_7\rangle$, and $\ker B^3\supset \langle e_1,...,e_9\rangle$. To get equality, we need to choose the blocks marked with asterisks carefully.

Thinking about it for a moment, one can see that the following works:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
that is, blocks just above the diagonal are of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}
I\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$
and the other off diagonal blocks are all zero.

Comment: Thanks. The matrix works but I do not see how you generate it. I can follow the argument of the span of the kernels of the first powers of $B.$ I do not see how you go from here. I thought using the Jordon block structure will provide easily the matrix but it didn't.